# Postgres complicated SQL query

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I'm trying to create a query through Postgres.  I have a table like this:

```
Date----------|Meter-----|------period-----|-----value
2017-05-23-----meter1  ---------- 1 ------------ 2.01
2017-05-23-----meter1  ---------- 3 ------------ 4.01
2017-05-23-----meter1  ---------- 4 ------------ 0.00
```

The table represents meter readings.  There needs to be 48x meter readings per day.  However sometimes for some reason a meter reading may not come through so there will be no record.  Also, a meter reading could be 0.00.

What I need to do is generate a series that gives me something like this if I search for meter readings for any given meter on a particular date:

```
Period----Total
1     ---   2.01
2     ---   null
3     ---   4.01
4     ---   0.00
.
.
.
```

It needs to give me 48 readings even if there is no record.  I'm trying to populate a google graph from a JSON response and the graph accepts null values but not 'no' values.

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `generate_series` to generate the numbers list and `left join` your table on to that and show missing periods as `null`.

```
select g.val,t.value
from generate_series(1,48) g(val)
left join tbl on t.period=g.val and t.date = '2017-05-23' --change this value as required
```

If you need it for all the dates and meters in the table, `cross join` generated periods with dates and meters and `left join` the table on to that.

```
select dm.date,dm.meter,g.val,t.value
from generate_series(1,48) g(val)
cross join (select distinct date,meter from t) dm
left join t on t.period=g.val and t.date=dm.date and t.meter=dm.meter
where dm.date = date '2017-05-23' --change this value as required
and dm.meter='meter1' --change this value as required
```

Comment: Great solution.  I think `t.meter = 'meter1'` is also needed as part of the `left join` condition in the first query.

Comment: Thanks guys, helped a lot! :)